# Extract the java.lang.reflect.Type of the parameterized type from an Option in Scala 3

Tags: java, scala, gson

the tldr; given something like `classOf[Option[String]]` be able to extract the options type, java.lang.String.

The full context is that I have a project that uses GSON to serialize/deserialize objects to scala 2.13. I have an option codec for GSON that works fine with Scala 2.13:

```scala
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

import com.google.gson._
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

class OptionSerializer extends JsonSerializer[Option[Any]] with JsonDeserializer[Option[Any]] {


  private def innerType(outerType: Type): Type = 
    outerType match {
      case pt: ParameterizedType => pt.getActualTypeArguments()(0)
      case _                     => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expected ParameterizedType")
    }
  

  override def serialize(
      src: Option[Any],
      typeOfSrc: Type,
      context: JsonSerializationContext
  ): JsonElement = {
    src match {
      case None    => JsonNull.INSTANCE
      case Some(v) => context.serialize(v, innerType(typeOfSrc))
    }
  }
  override def deserialize(
      json: JsonElement,
      typeOfT: Type,
      context: JsonDeserializationContext
  ): Option[Any] = {
    json match {
      case null                 => None
      case _ if json.isJsonNull => None
      case _                    => Some(context.deserialize(json, innerType(typeOfT)))
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to switch the project to Scala 3, this method no longer works because, apparently, `Option` in no longer a `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`.

```scala
  private def innerType(outerType: java.lang.reflect.Type): java.lang.reflect.Type = 
    outerType match {
      case pt: ParameterizedType => pt.getActualTypeArguments()(0)
      case _                     => throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expected ParameterizedType")
    }
```

I need a replacement for this `innerType` method that works with Scala 3.

Also, before anyone suggests that I move this to Circe, etc. This is a big codebase. Porting to Scala 3 is hung only on this one road block, whereas moving to Circe, etc. is a very big task.

EDIT ------

Below I've added a runnable sample code that works using [scala-cli](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/install/). Change the `using scala` line to `//> using scala "3.3.1"` to see the failure mode.

```scala
#!/usr/bin/env -S scala-cli shebang
// "2.13.12" or "3.3.1"
//> using scala "2.13.12" 
//> using lib "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1"

import java.lang.reflect.Type
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

import com.google.gson._
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

class OptionSerializer extends JsonSerializer[Option[Any]] with JsonDeserializer[Option[Any]] {


  private def innerType(outerType: Type): Type = 
    outerType match {
      case pt: ParameterizedType => pt.getActualTypeArguments()(0)
      case _                     => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Expected ParameterizedType. Found $outerType")
    }
  

  override def serialize(
      src: Option[Any],
      typeOfSrc: Type,
      context: JsonSerializationContext
  ): JsonElement = {
    src match {
      case None    => JsonNull.INSTANCE
      case Some(v) => context.serialize(v, innerType(typeOfSrc))
    }
  }

  override def deserialize(
      json: JsonElement,
      typeOfT: Type,
      context: JsonDeserializationContext
  ): Option[Any] = {
    json match {
      case null                 => None
      case _ if json.isJsonNull => None
      case _                    => Some(context.deserialize(json, innerType(typeOfT)))
    }
  }
}

// Pretend these are JPA entities. So mutable vars are required for this case
class Foo[A]() {
  var required: String = _
  var optional: Option[A] = None
  override def toString(): String = s"Foo($required, $optional)"
}
object Foo {
  def apply[A](required: String, optional: Option[A] = None): Foo[A] = {
    val foo = new Foo[A]
    foo.required = required
    foo.optional = optional
    foo
  }
}

def display(a: Foo[?], json: String, b: Foo[?]): Unit = {
  println("----------------")
  println(s"START: $a")
  println(s"JSON:  $json")
  println(s"END:   $b")
}

val gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .setPrettyPrinting()
      .registerTypeAdapter(classOf[Option[Any]], new OptionSerializer)
      .create()

val a = Foo("hello", Some(3))
val jsonA = gson.toJson(a)
val aa = gson.fromJson(jsonA, classOf[Foo[Int]])
display(a, jsonA, aa)

val b = Foo("hello", Some("world"))
val jsonB = gson.toJson(b)
val bb = gson.fromJson(jsonB, classOf[Foo[String]])
display(b, jsonB, bb)

val c = Foo("goodbye")
val jsonC = gson.toJson(c)
val cc = gson.fromJson(jsonC, classOf[Foo[String]])
display(c, jsonC, cc)
```

Comment: You say you don't get a `ParameterizedType`, what do you get instead? Also could you show us an example of code using the serializer?

Comment: @GaëlJ Done. I've added a sample script that can be run that demonstrates the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the behavior of `java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType()` differs between Scala 2 and 3. Here is a small example derived from your example which demonstrates this:

```scala
class Foo() {
  var f: Option[String] = None
}

val t = classOf[Foo].getDeclaredField("f").getGenericType()
println(s"$t ${t.getClass().getSimpleName()}")
```

In Scala 2 this prints "scala.Option<java.lang.String> ParameterizedTypeImpl" (as desired),
whereas in Scala 3 this prints "class scala.Option Class".

I assume this could be the underlying cause for this. [Dotty issue 17069 seems to track that](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/17069).

---

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Scala so this answer might be in parts incorrect. I was using https://scastie.scala-lang.org with Scala 2.13.12 and Scala 3.3.1 for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the compiler issue.